# SQL Case Statement that Evaluates Multiple columns and returns column that matches value criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, criteria

Thanks for the clarifications on the posting. I was trying to keep it simple, but here are some additional details/depth for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically I want to search through 3 different fields and identify the "Undergraduate" program first (if one exists).
If no valid undergraduate program exists, I then want to search for the "Graduate" Program (if one exists).
If no graduate program exists, then I want to search for the "Doctoral" Program.

I have 6 columns I'm trying to work with. Here's an example:

```
Program1    Program2    Program3    AcadLevel1  AcadLevel2  AcadLevel3
DNP.FNP     GR          NULL            DO          GR          NULL
MS.ACT      BS.BUAN     NULL            GR          UG          NULL
DNP.FNP     GR          NULL            DO          GR          NULL
EDD.EDLC    GR          NULL            DO          GR          NULL
MAED.EDL    EDD.EDLC    GR              GR          DO          GR
DNP.FNP     GR          UG              DO          GR          UG
```

I want to ignore all NULL values and I want to ignore any "GR", "UG", or "DO" in any of the Program1, 2, and 3 fields as they are not valid programs IDs. They should only be used here to identify the academic level of the program.

The end goal is to identify a single program. If there's an undergraduate program, that needs to be that program. If there's no undergraduate program, then the graduate program must be it. If there's no graduate program, the doctoral program. If there are 2 undergraduate programs, I don't care which one is included. And likewise if there are 2 graduate programs (and no undergraduate programs) either one will suffice.

One of the challenges that I'm facing is that there are many possibilities of how the programs are "laid out" in the three columns...there's no particular order or sequence.

Thanks again for any help/guidance and sorry for the earlier confusion.

###################### Update

Here's an example for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Program2,'')='' THEN Program1
       WHEN (AcadLevel1 = 'UG' and Program1 NOT IN ('UG','SP','GR','DO')) THEN Program1
       WHEN (AcadLevel1 = 'UG' and Program1 IN ('UG','SP','GR','DO')) THEN
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(Program2,'')='' THEN Program1 
             WHEN Program2 IN ('UG','SP','GR','DO') AND ISNULL(Program3,'')='' THEN Program2
             WHEN Program2 IN ('UG','SP','GR','DO') AND ISNULL(Program3,'')<>'' THEN Program3
             WHEN Program2 IN ('UG','SP','GR','DO') AND Program3 IN ('UG','SP','GR','DO') THEN Program1
             WHEN Program2 NOT IN ('UG','SP','GR','DO') AND ISNULL(Program3,'')='' THEN Program2
             WHEN Program2 NOT IN ('UG','SP','GR','DO') AND AcadLevel2 = 'UG' THEN Program2
             WHEN Program2 NOT IN ('UG','SP','GR','DO') AND AcadLevel3 = 'UG' AND Program3 NOT IN ('UG','SP','GR','DO') THEN Program3
             ELSE 'Other'
        END
 ELSE 'Other2' 
END AS 'Program_New'
```

I'm having difficulty analyzing every possible scenario between all of the fields to pull the correct Program value. And while I can keep writing additional CASE statements until I don't have any "other" error codes I still won't necessarily know if they fix all possible scenarios.

I was hoping for a more comprehensive and simple solution, but perhaps there is none...

Comment: Edit the question add some  sample data & desired result.

Comment: In your explanation, you use "MBA" as a program you're searching for, but your sample data doesn't have anything resembling "MBA". Also, it looks like you might be caught up in the "How do I do this" rather than the "What am I trying to do". Your question here, and the response you posted to Richard Hansell's answer makes me think you have an XY Problem. Read this page and then come back and tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish. http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, program1 VARCHAR(10), program2 VARCHAR(10), program3 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @table 
SELECT 1, 'MBA', 'ABM', 'XYZ'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'QWE', 'MBA', 'ABM';

SELECT
    id,
    CASE
        WHEN program1 = 'MBA' THEN 'program1'
        WHEN program2 = 'MBA' THEN 'program2'
        WHEN program3 = 'MBA' THEN 'program3'
        ELSE 'not found'
    END AS result
FROM
    @table;
```

Results:

```
id  result
1   program1
2   program2
```

---

So you want to take the results from the first query, then feed them into a second query, where you do something else with the results.  Yes, this is possible, but I'm really not sure where you are going with this, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, program1 VARCHAR(10), program2 VARCHAR(10), program3 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @table 
SELECT 1, 'MBA1', 'ABM', 'XYZ'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'QWE', 'MBA2', 'ABM';

WITH x AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        CASE
            WHEN program1 LIKE '%MBA%' THEN 'program1'
            WHEN program2 LIKE '%MBA%' THEN 'program2'
            WHEN program3 LIKE '%MBA%' THEN 'program3'
            ELSE 'not found'
        END AS result
    FROM
        @table)
SELECT
    *,
    CASE
        WHEN result = 'program1' THEN t.program1
        WHEN result = 'program2' THEN t.program2
        WHEN result = 'program3' THEN t.program3
    END AS not_sure_where_you_are_going_with_this
FROM
    x
    INNER JOIN @table t ON t.id = x.id;
```

My example is garbage btw, as you could do all of this easily in a single query.  So I think you need to provide some data/ expected results to get a better answer?

Comment: Close. And I think I left this off of the original question. Once I know "program1" in the first row, is there a way I can "use that" information in the "second part" of the query? 

So say I've identified "Program1" as having the value I'm interested in. Is there I can use that result? 

Meaning, can I write a second CASE statement that says WHEN result = "program1" THEN...

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `case` to check each column and `like` to check if the column contains the value `MBA`

```
select
    case
      when program1 like '%MBA%' then program1
      when program2 like '%MBA%' then program2
      when program3 like '%MBA%' then program3
    end col 
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f07619e7300f758ed7f8b7097d807393)

Comment: Thanks. This is close too, but see my comment below. I'm trying to then use that information in a "second" part of the query...so that I can pull "AcademicLevel1" (or 2 or 3) based on that info.

Comment: Post sample data and expected results. You should have done so from the start and not post a 2nd question in the comments of the 1st question.